# SonarQube 8.5.1 - Failed to Start Service - Wrapper Error

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

I cannot get sonarQube to start as a service. **SonaruQube server/console starts without issues.**

I tried to start the service via the supplied 'StartNTService.bat' as per docs ([SQ Docs](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/setup/operate-server/)) or via Windows Services GUI.
[image: start service]

Both display the following error:

[image]

The only log file that has an exception is 'wrapper.log':

"FATAL  | wrapper  | 2021/01/19 17:25:36 | **The argument 'Files\sonarqube\conf\wrapper.conf' is not a valid property name-value pair.**"

The above error line is duplicated every time I try to start the service. (I have verified permission settings). Not sure where else to look.

**wrapper.conf** was not modified by me in any way.

Service was installed via: [ sc create SonarQube binPath= ""C:\Program Files\sonarqube\bin\windows-x86-64\wrapper.exe" -s C:\Program Files\sonarqube\conf\wrapper.conf" ]

SonarQube Version: 8.5.1

Windows version: 10.0.18363

Java Version   : 11.0.9+7-LTS Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM

Any hints or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but the error is instantaneous.

Comment: How do you start the server? Add the executed command line, please. Did you modify the `wrapper.conf` file?

Comment: It looks like an issue with a space in the path (separated _Program Files_ into two distinct parameters). Your experience might be better if you choose to install the server in a path that does not include a space.

Comment: @agabrys I started the server using the provided StartSonar.bat file, see added image in question. I did not modify the wrapper.conf in anyway. ty!

Comment: @raspy - that was the issue (spaces in the path)- would you mind posting it as an answer so I can accept it. Thank you all very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like an issue with a space in the path (separated *Program Files* into two distinct parameters). Your experience might be better if you choose to install the server in a path that does not include a space.

Comment: Moving SonarQube files into D:\ solved the issue. Thank you.
New install script:
sc create SonarQube binPath= "\"D:\sonarqube\bin\windows-x86-64\wrapper.exe\" -s D:\sonarqube\conf\wrapper.conf"